# Recommended filters for sunrise/ocean landscape shot

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters, landscape, sunrise

What filters can I use to shoot a ocean/sunrise landscape shot?

I'll be shooting after dawn and I would like to make the water looks clear.

Comment: What is clear? Transparent or lighter?

Answer (score 4):

A circular polariser filter will reduce reflections from the surface of the water, making it appear clear.

Here a good example of this:

[image: With/without polariser]

Comment: Keep in mind that polarizers on wide angle lenses tend to create a polar result...one corner could be very dark while the other very light. Polarizers work great on normal and telephoto lenses, but you have to weight the consequences with wide angle lenses (which are usually used in landscape shots.)

Comment: Also keep in mind that shooting _into_ the sun, a polarizer will have no effect. Polarizers effect is maximized when 90* to the light source. The closer you are to facing directly *away from* or directly *in to* the light source (the sun), the less effect it will have.